# When I add an eventHandler or onClick to an element, where "is it"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick, eventhandler

If I dynamically create an element and then add an onclick="function()" to it, why doesn't that code get physically added to the element, the same way adding a class to it would?

Asking because I'm trying to pass a board game back and forth between players. I can send the innerHTML of the container element via AJAX to the next player and the physical game will load for them - but then any eventhandlers on dynamically created pieces are no longer there.

Do I have to create a function to put them back?  I don't think that would be too difficult, but if there was a way to get the onclick code to be written to the html page when added to the elements so that it passes in the innerHTML that would be much easier.

Comment: Changing the contents of `innerHTML` will re-render all elements inside of it. So basically you refresh all the elements. But regarding your events. When handling dynamic content you could either, like you suggested, re-add the event listeners, or use *event delegation* and listen for an event on the parent element of the dynamic content. (Most) events bubble up and can be captured on an element that doesn't change.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea.  Is there a way to do that with grid-display parents that have multiple dynamically created children in their grid?  I mean is there a way to put a listener for each separate grid space?   Or would I need to make a separate parent for each dynamically created element?

Comment: onclick / onXXX is evil: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/javascript-injection-tutorial/ you are basically hacking yourself

Comment: Okay so what should I do instead?  Is addEventListener better?  Or just as bad?

Comment: `addEventListener` is definitely the way to go. As for your other question, I would recommend giving your dynamically created elements something to identify them with, a `class`, `id` or `data-*` attribute can all help. Then listen of the grid parent and check the `target` property of the event. That will tell you inside what element the event has been fired.

Comment: Yes they all do have an id and class.  Okay I just read up on delegation. So I can have the parent fire the correct function by getting the ID or data- attribute or whatever from the child that was clicked.. that's great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass around the `innerHTML` via AJAX as you are currently, but using `onclick` is vulnerable to XSS attacks, unless you do some sort of JS obfuscation.

Easier than obfuscation would be to share common Javascript for both players with click handlers. Like this:

```
// Assign an ID for every button, and handle each event separately.
const buttonElement = document.querySelector('#btnOne');

// This is the equivalent of `onclick`
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  alert('Element clicked through function!');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

dynamically create an element, add event needs to use event delegation.

Comment: I didn't know about event delegation before. Looks like a great solution. But my dynamically (and randomly) created elements each have a dynamically created function based on what they are. So I'm guessing the best way would be to create an array with a reference to which element is in which position that the delegating function could reference to know which function to use depending on which element was clicked?  Unless there's a better way !